# How to create in Powershell Menu insight of Menu

Tags: powershell, menu

I came up with a little helpful script to help monitor and control Services on the remote servers:

```
do {
    $srv = Read-Host 'What is your ServerName?'
    $srvs = Read-Host 'What is ServiceName?'
    $userMenuChoice = Read-Host -Prompt "
    `n1. ServiceList
    `n2. Service Status.
    `n3. Stop Service.
    `n4. Start Service.
    `n5. Exit
    `nPlease Select Operation"

    switch($userMenuChoice){
        1{Get-Service -ComputerName $srv | select -property name,starttype}
        2{gsv -cn $srv -Name "$srvs*" | Out-String}
        3{Get-Service -Name "$srvs*" -ComputerName $srv | Stop-Service}
        4{Get-Service -Name "$srvs*" -ComputerName $srv | Start-Service}
        5{exit}
    }
} while ( $userMenuChoice -ne 4 )
```

Please, help me figure out  how I can get prompt  to keep the same server and service ( or NOT) and continue use same menu.
Something like: Before getting to MENU $userMenuChoice it will ask if I want to keep the same server Y/N (Y Default) Do you want to keep the same Service Y/N (Y Default)...

Also How  I Can clear screen before Proceeding to the next Menu.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Scope`.
`Variables` created in the block can only survive in that iteration of the block.

```
$A = "Hello"
While(1 -eq 1){
    $B = Read-Host 'Type Name?'
    "$A $B"
}
```

`$A` will forever be Hello because it was made outside the scope of While
`$B` will change forever because its inside the Scope of While.
(Also because each time you call while you are replacing $B with read-host anyways)

What you want to do is give a option on the ServerName and place a variable outside the scope of while.

```
$CurrentServer = $Null
$CurrentService = $Null
do {
    if(!($CurrentServer) -or $(Read-Host 'Change Server (Y,N)?') -eq "Y"){
        $CurrentServer = Read-Host 'What is your ServerName?'
    }

    if(!($CurrentService) -or $(Read-Host 'Change Service (Y,N)?') -eq "Y"){
        $CurrentService = Read-Host 'What is ServiceName?'
    }

    $userMenuChoice = Read-Host -Prompt @"
1. ServiceList
2. Service Status.
3. Stop Service.
4. Start Service.
5. Exit
Please Select Operation
"@
    switch($userMenuChoice){
        1{Get-Service -ComputerName $CurrentServer | select -property name,starttype}
        2{gsv -cn $CurrentServer -Name "$CurrentService*" | Out-String}
        3{Get-Service -Name "$CurrentService*" -ComputerName $CurrentServer | Stop-Service}
        4{Get-Service -Name "$CurrentService*" -ComputerName $CurrentServer | Start-Service}
        5{exit}
    }
} while ( $userMenuChoice -ne 4 )
```

The line

```
if(!($CurrentServer) -or $(Read-Host 'Change Server (Y,N)?') -eq "Y"){}
```

Allows for you to Change server and service if you wanted to But also allows you to skip it if needed.

It is saying if `$CurrentServer` is empty OR if `$CurrentServer` has value Ask Change Server, If Change Server is Y then run `if`

Answer (score 0):

This seems too easy. Put the `Read-Host` cmdlets outside of the loop.

```
$srv = Read-Host 'What is your ServerName?'
$srvs = Read-Host 'What is ServiceName?'

do {
  $userMenuChoice = Read-Host -Prompt "
  `n1. ServiceList
  `n2. Service Status.
  `n3. Stop Service.
  `n4. Start Service.
  `n5. Exit
  `nPlease Select Operation"
   switch($userMenuChoice){
     1{Get-Service -ComputerName $srv | select -property name,starttype}
     2{gsv -cn $srv -Name "$srvs*" | Out-String}
     3{Get-Service -Name "$srvs*" -ComputerName $srv | Stop-Service}
     4{Get-Service -Name "$srvs*" -ComputerName $srv | Start-Service}
     5{exit}
   }
 } while ( $userMenuChoice -ne 4 )
```

Comment: Great idea, Thank you! but it always will loop the same server without choice to change servers. Previous answer was perfect!